# Having trouble detecting my mistake in my coding

Tags: c

I am still new to C programming and I am having a bit of a problem in my coding. I am aware that I can't just ask for help without trying to fix it by myself first, so I tried fixing it and is still having the same problem.

My problem is, my coding displayed an incorrect calculation like below.

```
            ORDER PRICE SUMMARY
===========================================
 Customer No.      Total Order Price(RM)
===========================================
      1                  RM 40.00
      2                  RM 40.00
      3                  RM 478664371470163710000000000000000.00
===========================================
 Grand Total             RM 478664371470163710000000000000000.00
===========================================
```

Customer 1 and 2 showed the correct price but it just got messed up for Customer 3, which affects the grand total.

My coding is below, and it is obvious that I am using the simplest way of writing my code since my goal is to just answer a coding question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculatePrice(char);
void main()
{
  char comboType, addon;
  int comboQty, addonQty,i=1,j=1;
  float orderPrice = 0.00, comboPrice, addonPrice, grandPrice=0.00; // new float
  float customerPayment[3], allPrice[3]; // declare array



  printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf ("                     ~ SATAY RESTAURANT ~                     \n");
  printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf (" Combo Type                  Item                  Price (RM) \n");
  printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf ("     A        25 Chicken Stay + 25 Beef Satay        40.00\n");
  printf ("     B        30 Chicken Stay + 20 Mutton Satay      52.00\n");
  printf ("     C        10 Mutton Stay  + 40 Beef Satay        46.00\n");
  printf ("   Add-On      1 Ketupat                              0.60\n");
  printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");

  for (j=0;j<3;j++)
  {
      printf("\n Customer %d\n",j+1);
      printf("-------------");
      printf("\n Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end)  : ");
      scanf(" %c", &comboType);

      while (comboType != 'X' && comboType != 'x') // start while loop
      {
          comboPrice =  calculatePrice (comboType);
          printf(" Order Price for Combo %c               : RM%.2f \n ", comboType, comboPrice);
          printf("\n Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end)  : ");
          scanf(" %c", &comboType);
          allPrice[j] += comboPrice;
      }

      printf("\n Add-On Ketupat (Y/N)                  : "); // if X, ask for add-on
      scanf(" %c", &addon);

      if (addon != 'N' && addon != 'n')
      {
         printf(" Enter Ketupat Quantity                : ");
         scanf("%d", &addonQty);
         addonPrice = 0.60 * addonQty;
         allPrice[j] += addonPrice;
         printf(" Order price for Ketupat               : RM%.2f\n",addonPrice);
      }

      printf("\n Total Order Price for Customer %d      : RM%.2f\n\n",j+1, allPrice[j]);
      customerPayment[j] = allPrice[j];
  }

  printf("\n\n\n\t    ORDER PRICE SUMMARY ");
  printf("\n===========================================");
  printf("\n Customer No.      Total Order Price(RM)");
  printf("\n===========================================");

  for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
  {
      printf("\n      %d                  RM %.2f",i+1,customerPayment[i]);
      grandPrice += customerPayment[i];
  }

  printf("\n===========================================");
  printf("\n Grand Total             RM %.2f",grandPrice);
  printf("\n===========================================");

  getch ();
}

float calculatePrice (char comboType)
{
  float comboPrice, allPrice = 0.00;
  int comboQty;

     printf(" Enter Quantity                        : ");
     scanf("%d", &comboQty);

       if (comboType == 'A' || comboType == 'a')
        {
         comboPrice = 40.00 * comboQty;
        }

       if (comboType == 'B' || comboType == 'b')
        {
         comboPrice = 52.00 * comboQty;
        }

       if (comboType == 'C' || comboType == 'c')
        {
         comboPrice = 46.00 * comboQty;
        }

        return comboPrice;
}
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help detecting my mistake.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What were the inputs you entered to produce the above output?

Comment: Compile with -fsanitize=undefined and find the use of uninitialized variables

Comment: The array `float allprice[3]` has not been initialised. When you get to `allPrice[j] += comboPrice;` it's random what value you'll get. The advice for a beginner is **initialise every variable** such as `float allprice[3] = {0}`; This is also the first thing to look out for when you get surprising output with strange values. (A common similar problem can be not *reinitialising* a variable inside a nested loop.)

Comment: It is allso a good idea to use integers when dealing with monetary values. Count the cents and multiply with 100 when displaying Dollars, Euro or whatever. And when you do need floating point, use `double` rather than `float`.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning , you do not fill allPrice array with zeros, so you add to it what was left from memory.

Just at the start of your main, add `allPrice[3] = {0, 0, 0};` and `customerPayment[3] = {0, 0, 0};`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This worked like a charm and I am surprised by how simple my mistake was and I couldn't even detect it.